# Cambiar URL antes de enviar formulario

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

Hola tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
        {!! Form::open(['url'=>'/clientes/', 'method'=>"POST",'style'=>'display:inline-block']) !!}
    <input type="number" name="ruc_dni" placeholder="Ingresar Dni o Ruc">
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Lo que quisiera hacer es añadir a la url lo que llene en el imput, como lo podria hacer?
**'/clientes/lo-que-ponga-en-el-input'**

Comment: Podrias ser mas explicito?

Answer (score 0):

La solución en este caso la aporta JavaScript, puesto que pretendemos modificar un valor en el front-end, antes de enviar la ruta, por lo cual usaremos un parámetro genérico en la URL, el cual vamos a reemplazar al momento de enviar el formulario.

Por ejemplo, tenemos:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'/clientes/INPUT_TEXT', 'method'=>"POST", ['style'=>'display:inline-block', 'id'=>'form_clients']) !!}
    <input type="number" name="ruc_dni" placeholder="Ingresar Dni o Ruc" id="ruc_text">
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" id="submit_it" />
```

Al momento de hacer clic en el botón enviar vamos a cambiar la URL y luego sí enviamos el formulario.

Ejemplo rápido con jQuery (sin probar):

```
let submitButton = $('#submit_it');

submitButton.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let field_value = $('#ruc_text').val();
    let form = $('#form_clients');
    let url = form.attr('action').replace('INPUT_TEXT', field_value);
    form.submit();
});
```